# How to prevent row size growing to full page height if there's an overflow of elements?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a page with Bootstrap(4) containing 3 rows that would be visible at all times on the page but whenever I add elements to the middle row's column, if they're overflowing, the entire row expands height to full page thus overflowing other rows on the page.

Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

I've tried searching for the answer and I've been experimenting with suggestions that seemed related to my problem but I only managed to make it look worse.

Here's the crux of the code I've been working on.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid h-100 d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="row h-100" style="background-color: grey;">
    top<br>
  </div>
  <div class="row h-100" style="background-color: yellow;">
    <div class="col-lg-9 h-100" style="overflow-y: auto;">
      somethign1<br> somethign2
      <br> somethign3
      <br> somethign4
      <br> somethign5
      <br> somethign6
      <br> somethign7
      <br> somethign8
      <br> somethign9
      <br> somethign10
      <br> somethign11
      <br> somethign12
      <br> somethign13
      <br> somethign14
      <br> somethign15
      <br> somethign16
      <br> somethign17
      <br> somethign18
      <br> somethign19
      <br> somethign20
      <br> somethign21
      <br> somethign22
      <br> somethign23
      <br> somethign24
      <br> somethign25
      <br> somethign26
      <br> somethign27
      <br> somethign28
      <br> somethign29
      <br> somethign30
      <br> somethign31
      <br> somethign32
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 h-100 bg-danger"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 bg-primary h-100">s1<br>s2<br></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row h-100" style="background-color: green;">
    bottom<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you provide an image of the desired output??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you didn't set the overflow of row, it just shows all.
You can add

```
div.row {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Please check the following solution

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

div.row {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid h-100 d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="row h-100" style="background-color: grey;">
    top<br>
  </div>
  <div class="row h-100" style="background-color: yellow;">
    <div class="col-lg-9 h-100" style="overflow-y: auto;">
      somethign1<br> somethign2
      <br> somethign3
      <br> somethign32
      <br> somethign3
      <br> somethign32
      <br> somethign3
      <br> somethign32
      <br> somethign3
      <br> somethign32
      <br> somethign3
      <br> somethign32
      <br> somethign3
      <br> somethign32
      <br> somethign3
      <br> somethign32
      <br> somethign3
      <br> somethign32
      <br> somethign3
      <br> somethign32
      <br> somethign3
      <br> somethign32
      <br> somethign3
      <br> somethign32
      <br> somethign3
      <br> somethign32
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 h-100 bg-danger"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 bg-primary h-100">s1<br>s2<br></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row h-100" style="background-color: green;">
    bottom<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. 
Thank you for the swift reply.